# Fatal Error while deploying apex classes to production

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

I have created 3 new apex classes and test classes for the same.In sandbox, test class code coverage is more than 90% for all the classes. While trying to deploy to production, I am getting error as

> Code Coverage Failure
>   Your Code Coverage is 0%.You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
>
> Class A Name
>   Your Code Coverage is 0%.You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
>
> Class B Name
>   Your Code Coverage is 0%.You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
>
> Class C Name

Could anyone please let me know what is the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you include the test classes in your deployment? Do they pass? Are these the only failures? You haven't included the message for Class C.

Comment: Yes,I included the test classes in the deployment.While validating in the production, I am getting the above error.

Comment: Are the classes it errors on part of the deployment or not? Sometimes changes made in Production since the last deployment can invalidate existing unit tests.

Comment: Those classes are new Apex classes not existing apex classes

Comment: Are you including your records to test in the class test?

Comment: Also, without your code, is hard to help you...

Comment: Did you by any chance use seeAllData= true in your test classes ?

Comment: No...I didn't used seeAllData=true in my test class.

Answer (score 2):

If you use RunSpecifiedTests during deployment, *all* classes being deployed must individually meet the 75% requirement. Should you wish to deploy these classes without coverage (not recommended), you will need to use RunLocalTests as part of the deployment process. If you're using a Change Set, this should be the default setting. Otherwise, using the API, you must explicitly use the correct testLevel.

Answer (score 0):

According to me there are two possibilities:

1. Test class not added in the change set.
2. The test class is not having 'seeAllData=false'